# Access UITabBarController embedded in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a UITabBarController embedded in a UIViewController. I'm trying to access the UITabBarController instance from the parent UIViewController.

vc.children has a return type of [UIViewController] so the UITabBarController doesn't show up.

vc.tabBarController is nil because the view is not embedded in the TabBarController. My setup is the other way around.

Any ideas?

My storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution:
`vc.children.compactMap({$0 as? UITabBarController}).first` .

Best solution:
Select the `Embed Segue` from the storyboard and give an identifier (say "containerEmbedSegue". Next, in your vc:

```
var tabBarVC: UITabBarController?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "containerEmbedSegue" {
        self.tabBarVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work since vc.children is an empty array.

Comment: The second solution seems more promising but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to access the TabBarController from AppDelegate. I generate an instance of the parent ViewController and then try to access the embedded TabBarController. However, prepare() is never called. I've tried calling `vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "containerEmbedSegue")` but the app crashes with the following error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is required.'`

Comment: @Daniel From where did you try to access vc.children?

Comment: In the AppDelegate `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {`

Comment: And how you get the instance of the first vc?

Comment: Using the following class method:
`static func storyboardInstance() -> FirstViewController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? FirstViewController else {
            log.error("Unable to instantiate \(String(describing: self))")
            return nil
        }
        return vc
    }` I call storyboardInstance() in AppDelegate and it returns the firstVC with the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move `window?.rootViewController = viewController` before `vc.children`.